# ANDROID XML PARSING - URL

Tags: android, xml, parsing, url, uri

I have successfully parsed an XML file into a custom `ListView`, but how would I parse a URL from the XML into a button so when clicked takes the user to webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following Intent replacing obviously my wordpress site :)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.alchemiasoft.wordpress.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i need to parse the url from the xml i.e the url is different for every list item

Comment: "I have successfully parsed an XML..." seems that you have just parsed the xml ;) So if you want to attach a different action for every button you have to set the correct onClickListener on the button of every ListItem

Comment: so a onClickListener for the Intent - Uri.parse,

Comment: but for the Uri would the web address be TAG_URI??